# How to combine objects in a full outer join with Django?

Tags: python, django

Let's use Django's standard users and groups. I have a couple of users and groups and each user can be assigned to several groups via a M2M relation.

Now, I want to construct a single query which cross joins users x groups. The purpose is a view that shows all groups with it's members, when users are members of several groups then I want them to be shown in each group.

I currently have this query, which appears to give me a cross join:

```py
groups = list(Group.objects.all())
queryset = User.objects.filter(groups__in=groups)
```

However, the query only contains data about the users. How can I include the data for each group into the queryset?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the data for each group with annotation. The group objects are accessible through F objects.

Example:

```py
groups = list(Group.objects.all())
queryset = (
    User.objects.filter(groups__in=groups)
    .annotate(group_name=F("groups__name"))
)
```